# PHP Using Excel sheets remove formula

Tags: php, laravel

I want to modify an already existing excel sheet with delete the formula used in the sheets using PHP.

I tried to use php Spreadsheet. Not able to delete the formula used the excel sheets

Is there some way I can modify the already existing excel sheet with removing the formula using PHP?

Comment: you should post your code and the error message

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.